# How to load data from different property files based on query parameters from the rest API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, loose-coupling

I have a endpoint which exports the data from the database and I have another endpoint which imports the data . I want to export the data from the one database and import to other but that should be done at runtime , somewhat like this :
To export

```
http://localhost:8080/export?source=oracle
```

To import

```
http://localhost:8080/import?source=mariadb
```

This is how I am reading the property file currently:

```
@Component
public class ExportDBConfiguration extends DBConfiguration {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExportDBConfiguration.class);
    
    @Value("${export.database.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    
    @Value("${export.database.user}")
    private String dbUser;
    
    @Value("${export.database.password}")
    private String dbPassword;
    
    public Properties getDatabaseProperties() {
        LOG.info("Setting export database specific properties.");
        return getDatabaseProperties(dbUser, dbPassword);
    }
    
    public String getDBUrl() {
        String absoluteUrl = getDBUrl(dbUrl);
        LOG.info("Absolute db url is :: {} ", absoluteUrl);
        return absoluteUrl;
    }

}
```

To achieve this I thought of creating the separate properties file and then read from them based on the parameter source of the endpoint , but this approach is not working . Any idea how can it be done or a better approach to achieve this loose coupling ??

Answer (score 1):

You should use multiple `DataSources` in your Spring Boot App.

There are several Articles, Tutorials and SO answers that explain this topic.

For starters, you add the config of your `datasources` in the `application.properties` file:

```
# First Database
spring.datasource.url = [url]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
spring.datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

# Second DB
spring.secondDatasource.url = [url]
spring.secondDatasource.username = [username]
spring.secondDatasource.password = [password]
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName = [your Other Driver]

# To let Hibernate autodetect the Dialect
spring.jpa.database=default
```

Then create config classes for all your `DataSources`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "insert.your.repo.package.here" }
)
public class FirstDbConfig{
  
  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
  
  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("insert.your.entity.package.here")
      .persistenceUnit("firstDB")
      .build();
  }
    
  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
    entityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Then another Config class for your second DB:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager",
  basePackages = { "path.to.your.second.repo" }
)
public class SecondDbConfig {
 
  @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDatasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
  
  @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  barEntityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return
      builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("path.to.your.second.entities.package")
        .persistenceUnit("secondDB")
        .build();
  }
  @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
    @Qualifier("secondEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
    secondEntityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(secondEntityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

A lot of the part above is explained in [this](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7), [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases), and [this](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/multiple-data-sources-with-spring-boot/) article.

And then depending on what database name is in your query params, you use the specific Repos and Models.
You can of course add more than 2 `DataSources`.